# Facebook API getting post reactions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to make an api call to Facebook's Graph API (v17.0) to get information about reactions to a post. However, I get this error when I test the call on Postman

```
"(#200) Missing Permissions"
```

For context,I have implemented an OAuth2.0 flow that got me an access token with the 'email' and'public_profile' scopes.
Also, my app is  registered as a consumer app in the Facebook for developers portal.

I went through all available documentations for Facebook's API about the reactions functionality , but I can't find any lead about any special permissions I should need to make that call.

Comment: `email` and `public_profile` do not give you access to any posts. You would need `user_posts` permission if this is about a user post, or `pages_read_engagement` and `pages_read_user_content` for posts on a page feed.